# How do you see return value (numberOne + numberTwo) in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I know I can crate a variable and inspect the contents of the variable in the debugger, but is there something in the debugger that I can utilize to see what is being returned?

I have a semi-complex iOS application that is returning results in  numerous methods. I want to see the value (the result) being returned without adding code and without going back to the line that called the method.

How do you see return value (numberOne + numberTwo) in objective c?

If you have a function that returns a sum of a value i.e.:

```
-(int)mySum
{

    int numberOne =1;
    int numberTwo =2;

    return numberOne + numberTwo;
}
```

Comment: This isn't possible using the normal debugger. You'll have to either add a variable before the `return` statement with the sum (why not?), log the value, or inspect both elements and do the math yourself.

Comment: You won't see anything unless you call it. You could print it to the console with `NSLog` wherever you're calling it.

Comment: Add a breakpoint and copy the code into the action with a `po`

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by inserting a breakpoint at the last line of your mySum-function. When your application hits the breakpoint it gets paused and the debugger panel opens. you can there select "step out" (Debug>Step Out) and the result shows up on the bottom left side of your xcode window.

Alternatively you can type in "finish" and then "po $0" into lldb.
You can then type "c" into lldb to let the program continue.
For detailed instructions I found [this tutorial](http://iosdevtips.co/post/118205216313/xcode-breakpoint-method-return-value).